cludflare non-http tunnel no funciona
de antemano, gracias por su tiempo. 
Estoy intentando establecer un túnel no-HTTP con Cloudflare hacia mi dominio para exponer un servidor de Minecraft, pero no logro conectarme desde el cliente de Minecraft. La verdad es que no entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal. He intentado varias formas usando "cloudflared", configurando tanto el túnel como el DNS desde la consola, y también utilizando la interfaz web, pero no consigo conectarme.
He seguido la documentación: non-http
Entorno:
Contenedor Docker con el servidor de Minecraft.
En el mismo contenedor instalo cloudflared.
Pasos realizados:
Me conecto al contenedor y ejecuto los siguientes comandos:
curl -L --output cloudflared.deb https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/releases/latest/download/cloudflared-linux-amd64.deb && 
sudo dpkg -i cloudflared.deb && 
sudo cloudflared service install {mi_token}
cloudflared tunnel login
cloudflared tunnel create <tunelName>
nano ~/.cloudflared/config.yml
Configuración del archivo config.yml:

yaml
Copiar código
tunnel: <tunnel-uuid>
credentials-file: /home/pi/.cloudflared/<tunnel-uuid>.json 
ingress:
  - hostname: minecraft.mydomain.com
    service: tcp://localhost:25565
  - service: http_status:404

Creo el registro y entablo el tunel:
cloudflared tunnel route dns <tunnel-uuid> minecraft.mydomain.com
cloudflared tunnel run <tunnel-name>

Output:
cloudflared tunnel --loglevel debug run test_tcp
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z DBG Loading configuration from /home/coder/.cloudflared/config.yml
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF Starting tunnel tunnelID=<tunnel-uuid>
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF Version 2024.8.2
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.22.2, GoArch: amd64
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF Settings: map[cred-file:/home/coder/.cloudflared/<tunnel-uuid>.json credentials-file:/home/coder/.cloudflared/<tunnel-uuid>.json loglevel:debug]
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF cloudflared will not automatically update if installed by a package manager.
2024-08-10T15:41:37Z INF Generated Connector ID: <connector_id>
2024-08-10T15:41:38Z DBG Fetched protocol: quic
2024-08-10T15:41:38Z INF Initial protocol quic
2024-08-10T15:41:38Z INF ICMP proxy will use 172.23.0.4 as source for IPv4
2024-08-10T15:41:38Z DBG Failed to determine the IPv6 for this machine. It will use :: to send/listen for ICMPv6 echo
2024-08-10T15:41:38Z INF ICMP proxy will use :: as source for IPv6

maquina cliente:
cloudflared tunnel --hostname minecraft.mydomain.com --url tcp://localhost:25565
2024-08-10T18:30:13Z INF Start Websocket listener host=localhost:25565

Intento conectarme desde el lanzaor pero me dice conexion rechazada y en los logs no veo nada.
como i no pasara nada por el tunel.
cuando uso telnet:
telnet localhost 25565

cloudflare logs:
 DBG Websocket request: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: minecraft.mydomain.com
User-Agent: cloudflared/2024.8.2


2024-08-10T18:39:18Z DBG downstream->upstream copy: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF
2024-08-10T18:39:18Z DBG upstream->downstream copy: read tcp 127.0.0.1:25565->127.0.0.1:50927: use of closed network connection

luego intento:
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 25565 -InformationLevel Detailed
>>
ADVERTENCIA: TCP connect to (::1 : 25565) failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ComputerName            : localhost                                                                                     RemoteAddress           : 127.0.0.1                                                                                     RemotePort              : 25565                                                                                         NameResolutionResults   : ::1
                          127.0.0.1
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Loopback
IsAdmin                 : False
InterfaceAlias          : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress           : 127.0.0.1
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 0.0.0.0
TcpTestSucceeded        : True

cloudflare logs:
2024-08-10T18:41:11Z DBG Websocket request: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: minecraft.mydomain.com
User-Agent: cloudflared/2024.8.2


2024-08-10T18:41:11Z DBG downstream->upstream copy: read tcp 192.168.2.218:50937->172.67.184.158:443: use of closed network connection

esto tiene q funcionar o cloudlfare no lo permite?

Desde tu máquina cliente no tienes que usar cloudflared tunnel eso sólo está levantando un segundo túnel que no vas a ocupar. Para abrir la conexión a tu primer túnel, tienes que usar cloudflared access.
Debiera ser algo como:
cloudflared access tcp  --hostname minecraft.mydomain.com  --url 0.0.0.0:25565


Muchas gracias. Lo probé pero no funciono, abajo dejo mas detalles.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Acabo de probar el comando que me proporcionaste, pero aún no puedo conectarme.
El comando que estoy utilizando es:
cloudflared access tcp  --hostname minecraft.mydomain.com  --url 0.0.0.0:25565
Cuando intento conectarme desde el lanzador, se queda colgado un rato y luego muestra un mensaje de tiempo de espera agotado.
logs de cluflare:

2024-08-11T00:24:45Z ERR failed to connect to origin error="dial tcp: lookup minecraft.mydomain.com: getaddrinfow: El nombre solicitado es válido pero no se encontraron datos del tipo solicitado." originURL=https://minecraft.mydomain.com

y del lado del servidor de minecraft no veo ningún intento de conexión.
Que otra cosa me estoy aciendo mal?
